# What values are passed to the executor during the Promise object creation

Tags: javascript

In [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Parameters) it is stated that:

> The executor function is executed immediately by the Promise implementation,
>   passing resolve and reject functions (the executor is called before the Promise constructor even returns the created object).

What functions *resolve* and *reject* are used in the initial *executor*  execution during the object creation? There hasn't been any handler attached with .then at that point.

My understanding is that *executor* is a function passed to the Promise constructor taking two arguments: *resolve* and *reject* (which are functions themselves) . If *executor* is invoked at the Promise creation, what are the *resolve* and *reject* functions it is invoked with?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The executor function gets executed and for it to return value or to throw the error to the promise handlers, it needs some callback. These callbacks should be available in the scope of execution and should be available from the promise. This is the purpose of the `resolve` and `reject` values passed by the constructor of the promise in the below example.

```
var a = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) //resolve or reject on 50% probability
      resolve('this value to the handler');
    else
      reject('uh oh! there is an error');
  },2000);
});
```

now, if you attach `.then()` or `.catch()` on `a`. The above `setTimeout` will pass the values through the resolve and reject callbacks that we had provided.

so, think of `resolve` and `reject` as some values provided to the executor to communicate back with the original promise handler.

Comment: thanks for you answer. So When it says that at the promise creation, the executor is called _passing resolve and reject functions_ it uses some internally defined resolve and reject functions? Could be like (result) => { return result } ?

Comment: Yes. Like callbacks. (callback) => { // ...do something asynchronous; return callback(); }

Comment: where to find the source code of `Promise` constructor ?